# what kind of case does the object in comparative sentence take?

Tags: grammatical-case

I was reading about comparative & superlative and saw this sentence in the example

> Er ist stärker als ich

Both pronouns *er* and *ich* take nominative case that make me unsure if this sentence is written right or not. Isn't it should be *mir* or *mich* (I think it's *mir* but I'm not sure)

Comment: Your example is perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi, can you explain why the object then take nominative case but not dative or accusative. Is it happen only for comparative sentence

Comment: In a comparison you usually have to nominatives: _who is stronger/bigger/whatever than who?_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cases of the two things that are compared agree:

> **Er** ist stärker als **ich**.
>
> Das bereitet **ihm** stärker als **mir** Probleme.
>
> Das betrifft **ihn** stärker als **mich**.
>
> Das ist stärker **sein** als **mein** Problem.

(Not quite happy with all of these examples.)

Comment: Why not replace "stärker" with "mehr"? It will be difficult to find examples for all cases with "stärker".